How to quickly ignore a tag from the question list? Since a few days ago only the "Watch Tag" button is available when hovering a tag with the mouse
Since a few days ago, when I my mouse goes over a question tag of the StackOverflow question list, I can only choose to add that tag to my watched tag list.

If I want to put it in my ignore list instead, I can, but I have click on the edit link of the Ignored Tags box on the right of the question list, then retyping that tag name here and validate:

But this behavior is different than the one of, for example, StackOverflow Meta I am currently posting into, where when my mouse goes over a tag it displays instead:

which allows me to ignore a tag in a single click.
Why was the popup changed?
How do I ignore a tag quickly now?
